# How to describe the partition for the given equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

The equivalence relation I am given is:

$xRy$ iff $x^2=y^2$

I am asked to describe the partition and write it out.

I started by looking at say both $x$ and $y$ can either be negative of positive. Then I concluded that $-x=y$ or $x=y$ but I am not too sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a fine description of the partition through your
assertion
$$
xRy\iff x^{2}=y^{2}\iff|x|=|y|.
$$
 You can be more explicit by defining the partitions by $[x]=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\colon xRy\}$
for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. That is, $[x]$ is the partition which
contains $x$ and all elements equal to it, namely $-x$. That is, $[x]=\{x,-x\}$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (note that this also works for $0$, since $0=-0$ and we get $[0]=\{0\}$).

Comment: then would I have to find the partition with respect to y as well and combine them?

Comment: I don't know what is expected of you (I am assuming this is a homework assignment). Personally, I would give full marks to any reasonable answer that demonstrates that the student knows how to construct the partition.

Comment: yes its a homework assignment and it asks to give a description of what the partition would look like so I assume it wants me describe what happens both in the case of x and y So some things like P={.....}

Comment: How about writing $P=\{ \{0\}, \{-1,1\}, \{-2,2\}, \ldots \}$?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of writing something like this but since I wants only a description I am not sure how to say this in words too well;

Comment: I think what I wrote above is sufficient. Don't think too much about this stuff. Your professor/TA is just a human being who will do their best to interpret your answer. Write it like you would explain it to anyone else in the course.

Comment: I wrote my answer as P={{0},{-1,1},{-2,2},...} If we are given a negative x value we will get a positive y value and if we are given a positive x value we get a positive y value, Given x=0 we get y=0. Our relation goes from x to y so we focus on the sign of x.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the equivalence class for each element:

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $[x]=\{y/|y|=|x|\}$.